# Focusing embedded SWF in Firefox when page is loaded

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, firefox, focus

Flex app I'm currently working on needs to have a TextInput control focused when the app is started but as I noticed when implementing this, a call to TextInput.focus() will focus the input but not embedded SWF itself, therefore user can't type to the input right away after app starts and must click somewhere on the SWF before that. I partially solved this issue by using some JS to automatically set focus to my SWF (tested and working with Chrome v27 and IE10). Too bad it does not work on Firefox (v22). Why is that? Here's my code from index.html template:

```
function focusFlash() 
{ 
    var f = document.getElementById('${application}');

    if(f) 
    {
       f.tabIndex = 0;
       f.focus();
    }
}
```

I use this function as a swfobject.embedSWF() callback.

Comment: I've seen this question here before, but can't seem to find it. Anyways: http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/2011/12/15/setting-focus-in-flex-components

Comment: The code you provided is same as mine, the only difference being that it's called from the app itself. Does it really work on FF? Also, pure JS solution would better suit me.

Comment: I just run your code, still no focus on FF v22.

Answer (score 0):

This, from Adobe forums, might be worth trying?...

Add the following lines to your swf.

import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.call("s = function() { document.getElementById('mymovie').focus(); }");

where 'mymovie' is ID of embedded swf object in html script.

Comment: This is similar to what I am doing now, just that without setting tabIndex it only works in IE.